# what is curl -u equivalent in php unirest

Tags: php, api, curl, unirest

what is `curl -u` equivalent in **php unirest**

Blockscore API:

```
$ curl https://api.blockscore.com/people \
  -u sk_test_n5049aa6053c9a0217bea78070fbf501: \
  --header "Accept: application/vnd.blockscore+json;version=4"
```

> Api key: sk_test_n5049aa6053c9a0217bea78070fbf501

I want to try this out in **Unirest**. but what is `-u`? 
is it a header or a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-u` flag for cURL is used to set the credentials for HTTP Basic authentication. The provided credentials will be base64-encoded and presented in the "Authorization" header as in:

```
Authorization: Basic c2tfdGVzdF9uNTA0OWFhNjA1M2M5YTAyMTdiZWE3ODA3MGZiZjUwMTo=
```

So it is a header.

In unirest you should be able to use:

```
Unirest\Request::auth('sk_test_n5049aa6053c9a0217bea78070fbf501', '');
```

Comment: Authorization is  -u then what is --u?